# navigator.mediaSession.metadata not updating after page reload

Tags: mediasession

I am currently tying our audio player with mediaSession.
Everything is working as it should, when I hit play and update `navigator.mediaSession.metadata`, it's properly displayed in the notification on desktop and mobile.

But after I reload the page and hit play, the notification has always default values (website URL as a title and `link rel="icon"` for the artwork). This only happens after I reload the website. If I close it and open again the notification is working properly again.

Here's how it's done:

```js
//...
initialConfiguration: {
    title: 'Initial Title',
    artist: 'Initial Artist',
    album: '',
    artwork: [
        { src: "initial/artwork/url.jpg", sizes: "512x512", type: "image/jpg" },
    ]
},
currentMetadata: null,
setMediaSessionMetaData: function(){
    let self = this;
    if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
        if( !self.currentMetadata ){
            self.currentMetadata = new MediaMetadata(self.initialConfiguration);
        }else{
            // Update existing metadata
            self.currentMetadata.title = "New Title";
            self.currentMetadata.artist = "New Artist";
            self.currentMetadata.artwork = [
                { src: "new/artwork/url.jpg", sizes: '512x512', type: "image/jpg" },
            ];
        }
        navigator.mediaSession.metadata = self.currentMetadata;
    }
},
//...
```

This function works perfectly fine on first page load, when I hit play for the first time it loads the `initialConfiguration` and if I call the function again the title and artwork gets updated. But after reload, the notification has always default values ignoring my configuration.

Is there a bug in `mediaSession`, I didn't find anything regarding this issue on mediaSession github page (https://github.com/w3c/mediasession/issues) and searching this issue gives me zero results.

Comment: I seem to be running into the same problem. Did you ever figure out why it resets to default?

Comment: I ran into exactly this problem with Chrome and Edge (on Win10). Now I tried it with the latest Firefox and there it runs like a charm. (Also, the Spotify web player has the same issue, so I don't think it's us doing the wrong thing.) I assume this is a bug is in the Chromium codebase. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

After Searching for days and not finding anything....
I discovered a workaround. It has to do with the `performance.navigation.type` when you first open a page it is set to 0 and after a refresh it gets set to 1. I was curious if this had any effect on the `mediasession` so I figured out how to "Hard Refresh" the page by using `window.open(window.location.href, "_self");`, because apparently that generates a "Hard Refresh". After that the `mediasession` works again. so what I did was setup an onload function that checks to see if `performance.navigation.type == 1` and if so then do a "Hard Refresh"

```
    window.onload = function() {
    
        if (performance.navigation.type != 0) {
    
            window.open(window.location.href, "_self");
    
        }
    };
```

Now when the user refresh's it will do a "Hard Refresh".
Also make sure to move the `window. Onload` line to the end of the javascript file or after the initial function